# Angular+Express - data not binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, express

I'm using Express to serve Angular templates and scripts. My `public/views/index.html` is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app='eventsApp' ng-controller='EventController'>
        {{event.name}} <br />
        {{event.location}} <br />
    </div>


    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/app.js'</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `public/javscripts/app.js` is:

```
(function() {
  var EventController, eventsApp;

  eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);

  EventController = function($scope) {
    return $scope.event = {
      name: 'angular bootcamp',
      location: 'SF'
    };
  };

  eventsApp.controller('EventController', EventController);

}).call(this);
```

But my webpage just shows

```
{{event.name}} 
{{event.location}}
```

without substituting the values. What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the surrounding function from the declaration of the middle and the controller.

Comment: You didn't close your second script tag.

Comment: But that would leak the module and controller variables into the global namespace. Why should that matter anyway? The 'angular' variable is global, and ng-app should look for all modules defined on it, no?

Comment: oh man, I'm blind as a bat. Thanks a lot @francisco.preller. I'll accept it if you add your comment as an answer.

Comment: A second pair of eyes is generally a godsend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a syntax error. Simply close your second script tag.